# Django : Multiple class choices for OneToOneField

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, one-to-one

I would like to find a solution to be able to set "**multiple choices**" in **OneToOneField** relation. I want to be allowed to **choose between two classes**.

Here is the context :

If I have two classes : ClassOne and ClassTwo like this :

```
class ClassOne(models.Model):
    something = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class ClassTwo(models.Model):
    something = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I need to create **an Agenda** (where I will put events) which **can be linked either to ClassOne or to ClassTwo**.

I need to do something like this :

```
class Agenda(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField( ClassOne or ClassTwo , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

At the end I would like to be allowed to do that :

```
agenda_one = Agenda(owner = ClassOne, description = "")
agenda_two = Agenda(owner = ClassTwo, description = "")
```

Do you have an idea about how to achieve this ?

Comment: You should be able to do it with [class inheritance](https://godjango.com/blog/django-abstract-base-class-multi-table-inheritance/), but I never tried, good luck!

Comment: If I undersntand : if I use class inheritance, I need to create two subclasses for Agenda. Therefore I couldn't access the agenda the same way for both classes.